# 19年前にリリースされたsqlite-1.0.1はどのようにしてコンパイルしますか

Tags: sqlite, gcc

SQLiteのソースコードを読みながら、その絡繰を勉強したいんですが。DBの最も基本的な機能だけに興味があり、それに、[sqlite-1.0.1](https://www.sqlite.org/src/info/e8521fc10dcfa02f) にはただ１万行くらいのソースコードがあるから、今多くのプロジェクトで応用されているsqlite3よりも読みやすいと思います。

残念なことに、今のgccでは、19年前のsqlite-1.0.1がコンパイルできないようです。

```
wget "https://www.sqlite.org/src/tarball/e8521fc1/SQLite-e8521fc1.tar.gz"
tar xzvf SQLite-e8521fc1.tar.gz
mkdir bld && cd bld
../SQLite-e8521fc1/configure --prefix=/opt/sqlite-1.0.1 --with-tcl=no
make
```

仮想コンピュータによって、古いFedora Core release 3をインストールして、ビルトインのgcc(gcc version 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3))でsqlite-1.0.1をコンパイルしてみたが、`make`を実行すると、以下のエラーメッセージが表示されます。

```
gcc -std=c89 -g -O2 -o lemon ../SQLite-e8521fc1/tool/lemon.c
In file included from ../SQLite-e8521fc1/tool/lemon.c:29:
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/3.4.2/include/varargs.h:4:2: #error "GCC no longer implements <varargs.h>."
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/3.4.2/include/varargs.h:5:2: #error "Revise your code to use <stdarg.h>."
```

`Makefile`では、`-std=c89`を`gcc`のパラメータとして追加してみたが、またコンパイルできません。

上記のエラーメッセージからして、gcc version 3.4.2はsqlite-1.0.1にとって、現代的なコンパイラであるかもしれません。

`<varargs.h>`が`<stdarg.h>`に取り替えられた[check in](https://www.sqlite.org/src/info/7902e4778ec86e25)があり、そして、SQLiteの作者は「1989年にgccを使って`lemon.c`をコンパイルしたのを覚えている」というコメントをそのcheck inに書き留めました。

もしかして、もっと古いgccを探す必要でしょう。こういう古いものどこから入手できますか。19年前には、プログラマ達はどのようなOSやコンパイラを使っていましたか。

Comment: v1.0.1をビルドする目的は何ですか？ 最初の段落を読む限りビルドしなくてもソースコードを確認するだけで十分に感じられました。そしてこのスレッドではどのような回答を求めていますか？

Answer (score 1):

とりあえずv1.0.1をビルドしたく、そして`<varargs.h>`が原因でビルドできず、`7902e477`で改善されていることが把握できているのであれば、[当該パッチ](https://www.sqlite.org/src/vpatch?from=e76787f877c456ab&to=7902e4778ec86e25)を適用してはどうでしょうか？ コメントが変更されているため前後３行無視してやることで適用できます。

```
patch -F 3 < 7902e477.patch
```

Answer (score 1):

Fedora Core release 3が 2004年リリースなので新しすぎるのかもしれませんね。
当時は Slackware か Redhat が主流だった？と思いますので それらで試してみるのはどうでしょう。

http://archive.download.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/
https://mirrors.slackware.com/slackware/

Redhatなら6.2、Slackwareなら 3.9～7.1 あたりがちょうど良さそうです。